# Is there a way to Call with skype in my LAN without internet connection?

Tags: networking, skype, voip

Is there a way to Call with skype in my LAN without internet connection ?

If yes, tell me how please ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is set up a SIP server on your LAN. There are several, then you'll be able to use SIP clients like Ekiga, or whatever the windows one is called, to get Skype-like (VOIP) functionality. There are loads of such servers, like asterisk or freeswitch.

Answer (score 1):

Without Internet connection, you won't be able to use Skype. But, as @Ninefingers pointed out, there are other VoIP solutions you could use locally.